# Create object array based on value of another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an object array like this:

```
const user = [
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'Frank' }
]
```

But I need to get an array like this:

```
const result = [
  { key: 'Bob', value: 'Bob', text: 'Bob' },
  { key: 'Frank', value: 'Frank', text: 'Frank' }
]
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
const result = []
user && user.length > 0 && user.map(u => {
  result.push({ key: u.name, value: u.name, text: u.name })
})
```

But is there another way to do this a bit more straight? Do I really need to build each object and push it into a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.map()` you should return the new element from the callback function. If you don't return something, you should be using `.forEach()`.

And you can use destructuring to avoid repeating `u.name`.

```
result = user ? user.map(({name}) => ({ key: name, value: name, text: name })) : [];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could construct the array all at once using `.map` and using `Object.fromEntries` on an array of entries:

```js
const user = [
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'Frank' }
];
const result = user.map(({ name }) => Object.fromEntries(
  ['key', 'value', 'text'].map(key => [key, name])
));
console.log(result);
```

If `user` might be undefined, you can alternate it with the empty array first:

```
const result = (user || []).map(...
```

There's no need to test `user.length` first, because if the length is 0, the result will remain the empty array, since there aren't any items to map over.

Comment: What if `user` is undefined or empty array?

Comment: If it's an empty array, the result will be an empty array too - using `.map` on an empty array doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't go through any iterations.

Comment: Is there an advantage using two `map()` instead of doing it like @Barmar ?

Comment: I did it that way in order to be less repetitive. If you have a bunch of keys that you want for the new objects, you can just add them to the array inside the `fromEntries` callback, instead of having to list both the new key and the `name` again every time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax to create new fields in your object.

`result["key"] = u.name`

Comment: `result` is an array, not an object.

Comment: `result[index]["key"] = u.name` than. It's an object array. This way you can assign key to something even if there is no key value in the object.

Comment: Why is this better than the way he's doing it with `push()`?

Comment: There's no `result[index]` until AFTER he pushes the object into it.

Comment: `const user = [
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'Frank' }
];
for ( var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) result["key"] = user[i].name;
console.log(result);` It just works.

Comment: `result` should be an array like `[
  { key: 'Bob', value: 'Bob', text: 'Bob' },
  { key: 'Frank', value: 'Frank', text: 'Frank' }
]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use @barmar's `map()` function or this `reduce()` function:

```
const result = user.reduce((res, u) => {
    res.push({ key: u.name, value: u.name, text: u.name }); return res
}, [])
```

[JavaScript has a Reduce Method. You Should Use It.](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/javascript-has-a-reduce-method-you-should-use-it-ff4dd29d6c9d)

Comment: Just because you *can* use `reduce()` doesn't mean you *should*. If it's identical to `map()`, use `map()`. `reduce()` is appropriate if you want to collect conditionally.

Comment: Correct, `reduce()` provides more functionality than `map()` does.  It's not limited to returning an array, either.

Comment: But IMHO it should only be used when the extra flexibility is needed. Other uses are often more confusing than helpful. It seems like some people here view almost every loop as requiring a demonstration of reduce's power.

Comment: That doesn't make this answer wrong, it provides a valid option with more potential while acknowledging your answer

Comment: Never said it was wrong, although I think that sometimes answers that use reduce when other solutions are simpler are just showing off their cleverness.

Comment: FYI, I wasn't the downvoter, if that's what you assumed.

Comment: IMHO, the biggest value of StackOverflow is not only finding an answer, it's also in finding options.  This answer is for JS newbies who are still learning functional programming tools, discovering options learning when to use them.  There's always more than one way to solve a problem.